# Debugging Prerelease Issue

Tags: ros, ros-electric, pre-release, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Console Output from Failed Build](http://build.willowgarage.com/job/prerelease_electric_wu_ros_tools_lucid_i386/3/console)

Possible error locations:

- building 'coverage.tracer' extension
- E: Couldn't find package ros-electric-ros

[Tagged Source Code](https://code.google.com/p/wu-robotics/source/browse/#svn%2Ftags%2Fwu_ros_tools%2Felectric)

**Edit** New Error:

```
rosdep: error: Unsupported command init.

Global exception caught. Generating email.  Exception: 
. Check the console output for test faCommand failed, closing out ramdisk
Command failed: Command '['sudo', 'chroot', '/home/rosbuild/chroot/prerelease_electric_wu_ros_tools_oneiric_amd64', 'su', 'rosbuild', '-s', '/bin/bash', '-c', "HUDSON_URL='http://build.willowgarage.com/' BUILD_URL='http://build.willowgarage.com/job/prerelease_electric_wu_ros_tools_oneiric_amd64/6/' BUILD_TAG='hudson-prerelease_electric_wu_ros_tools_oneiric_amd64-6' JOB_NAME='prerelease_electric_wu_ros_tools_oneiric_amd64' BUILD_ID='2012-11-12_08-41-51' BUILD_NUMBER='6' JOB_URL='http://build.willowgarage.com/job/prerelease_electric_wu_ros_tools_oneiric_amd64/' EXECUTOR_NUMBER='0' /tmp/script.sh"]' returned non-zero exit status 255
ilure details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/install_dir/ros_release/job_generation/src/job_generation/run_auto_stack_prerelease.py", line 60, in main
    call("rosdep init")
  File "/tmp/install_dir/ros_release/job_generation/src/job_generation/jobs_common.py", line 466, in call
    raise Exception
```

**Edit 2**: [New Error Console Output](http://build.willowgarage.com/job/prerelease_electric_wu_ros_tools_maverick_amd64/6/console)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47025/debugging-prerelease-issue/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-10-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-11-12**:
Do you have a link to the job with the new error, the latest one on hudson looks like the original problem?

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-11-12**:
It looks like the wrong version of rosdep is being used at that point.  Which is really odd because earlier in the build rosdep init and rosdep update are called successfully.  Let me ask around the office about this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you are running the ROS build farm pre-release tests.

I have not had much luck running legacy pre-release tests recently, either. Most attention is currently focused on the new catkin and bloom-based build farm.

Your question will probably get more response on the `ros-release@code.ros.org` mailing list.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the relavent line from that:

```
E: Couldn't find package ros-electric-ros
```

I'll look into it.

UPDATE:

I am able to install ros-electric-ros on Lucid, which is what the pre-release are running.  There might have been an interruption of service, can you try this prerelease again?

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2012-11-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-11-12**:
Tried again, got new error, posted above.

**Comment by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on 2012-11-19**:
The ros package of electric is indeed missing for lucid: http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-electric-ros/

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-11-19**:
This is most likely a debian repository sync'ing problem.